# winforms static class to Web

Tags: c#

I have a winforms application that calls an assembly that has a static class.
This class is big with user ,system and other configuration options.

I'm starting to port the application to Web.
I want to reference the assembly, but the class is static, so, all users will have the same values and that can't happen.

Is there a way around this (maintaining the original asembly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You will have to change the code.

Comment: Tkx for the reply. I guess that's it.

Answer (score 0):

A static class is usually a helper class. You can still use that class methods with a few changes..

Simply make the class public and change all static methods to public. This should be a quick change.

While static variabes can be used in Web App, they are not thread-safe.

If you want to share variables across different users, try using the Application object.